# Hive variable is not setting inside the query file

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am connecting hive through beeline and passing hivevar to create the table in hive but inside the file the variables are not getting set.below is the code where I have set all the value. when I do echo all values are set properly and displayed.

```
beeline -u "${HIVE_CON}" --hivevar DB_NAME=${DB_NAME} --hivevar name=${tblName} --hivevar fileLocation=${fileLocation} --hivevar hiveSchema="${hiveSchema}" -f ${CRT_TBL_NOT_PRQ_QUERY_FILE}

Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2 use ${hivevar:DB_NAME};
No rows affected (0.235 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive
0: jdbc:hive DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${hivevar:name};
No rows affe
0: jdbc:hive
0: jdbc:hive CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ${hivevar:name}
0: jdbc:hive (
0: jdbc:hive    ${hivevar:hiveSchema}
0: jdbc:hive )
0: jdbc:hive LOCATION '${hivevar:fileLocation}';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just use ${var_name} inside hive query

For eg: the following works.

```
beeline -u <connection_string> --hivevar table_name=temp_table1 -e 'create table ${table_name} (i int);'
```